# JSON parsing in a for loop in R

Tags: json, r, for-loop, rcurl, rjson

I'm trying to write a for loop that will take zip codes, make an API call to a database of Congressional information and then parse out only the parties of congressmen representing at zip code.

The issue is that some of the zip codes have more than one congressman and others have none at all, (an error on the part of the database, I think). That means I need to loop through the count returned by the original pull until there are no more representatives.

The issue is that the number of congressmen representing each zip code is different. Thus, I'd like to be able to write new variable names into my dataframe for each new congressman. That is, if there are 2 congressmen, I'd like to write new columns named "party.1" and "party.2", etc.

I have this code so far and I feel that I'm close, but I'm really stuck on what to do next. Thank you all for your help!

EDIT: I found this way to be easier, but I'm still not getting the results I'm looking for

```
library(rjson)
library(RCurl)

zips <- (c("10001","92037","90801", "94011")

test <- matrix(nrow=4,ncol=7)
temp <- NULL
tst <- NULL

for (i in 1:length(zips)) {
   for (n in length(temp$count)) {
       temp <- (fromJSON(getURL(paste('https://congress.api.sunlightfoundation.com/legislators/locate?zip=', 
                                 zips[i],'&apikey= 'INSERT YOUR API KEY', sep=""), .opts = list(ssl.verifypeer = FALSE))))
    tst <- try(temp$results[[n]]$party, silent=T)
      if(is(tst,"try-error"))
        test[i,n] <- NA
      else
        test[i,n] <- (temp$results[[n]]$party)
  }
}
```

Comment: I maintain an R client for Sunlight APIs https://github.com/ropengov/rsunlight

Comment: Thanks Scott, but is there a way to do it within the loop? I need to move the results to a dataframe and I'm a bit lost on how to do it from your client.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by move to a data.frame. The output in the `results` slot is a data.frame, if there is in fact data for that zip code. Just index to `results` to get the data.frame.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. Eventually what I want to do is feed in a list of about 90 zip codes and then just extract party affiliations for members of the house. Is that possible with your client? Should I make another question in SO for this?

Comment: that should be easy, i'll edit the answer below

Comment: made an edit below, just a simple one liner with `lapply()` if all you need is party

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
install.packages("rsunlight")
library("rsunlight")
zips <- c("10001","92037","90801", "94011")
out <- lapply(zips, function(z) cg_legislators(zip = z))
# results for some only
sapply(out, "[[", "count")
# peek at results for one zip code
head(out[[1]]$results[,1:4])

bioguide_id   birthday chamber                                                    contact_form
1     S000148 1950-11-23  senate         http://www.schumer.senate.gov/Contact/contact_chuck.cfm
2     N000002 1947-06-13   house https://jerroldnadler.house.gov/forms/writeyourrep/default.aspx
3     M000087 1946-02-19   house                   https://maloney.house.gov/contact-me/email-me
4     G000555 1966-12-09  senate                       http://www.gillibrand.senate.gov/contact/
```

You can change as needed within a lapply or for loop to add columns, etc.

To pull out party could be as simple as `lapply(zips, function(z) cg_legislators(zip = z)$results$party)`.